# What is the difference between BeanFactory and FactoryBean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

How to introduce the difference by clearly describe? i know beanfactory is used to generate bean
,so the FactoryBean is used to generate fatory? which one is earlier to execute?
I tried read the official introduce but cannot understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BeanFactory is the core of SpringBoot. It manages all the beans and has the functionality to maintain the beans. It is used in inversion control.

FactoryBean is more like a datatype where you can create and use a bean as an object. It is an interface.